# Cross-validation with class imbalance

Tags: python, xgboost, imbalanced-data

I am trying to train XGBOOST in a binary classification setting, with positive to negative instances at a 1:5 ratio. My data draws parallels to the likes of cancer detection, i.e. FNs are much more costly than FPs. After quite a bit of reading, I am still confused about the following:

First, is it necessary for me to balance the classes e.g by over-sampling? I have a data size of around 160,000, with many entries containing NaN for certain columns. Regarding XGBOOST in particular, I know it is common to adjust `scale_pos_weight`, but the documentation (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/param_tuning.html) notes that this is mainly for overall AUC performance. The main metric I care about is recall, but also accuracy to an extent.

Secondly, what metric should I try to maximise in the hyper-parameter tuning?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FNs are much more costly than FPs

You can create your own objective function based on some estimation of cost of false negatives and false positives. The documentation is [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html), here is the example based on which you can get inspired:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def your_objective(predt: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> Tuple[str, float]:
    y = (dtrain.get_label() > 0.5) * 1
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y, predt).ravel()

    your_gain = true_positive_cost * tp - false_positive_cost * fp
    max_gain = true_positive_cost * (fn + tp)

    result = your_gain / max_gain
    return 'your_objective', result

xgb.train(your_params,
          dtrain=dtrain,
          num_boost_round=10,
          obj='binary:hinge',
          feval=your_objective,
          evals=[(dtrain, 'dtrain'), (dtest, 'dtest')],
          evals_result=results)
```

You just need to define `true_positive_cost` and `false_positive_cost`.
And yes, do perform adjustment of classes with `scale_pos_weight` depending on the ratios of the classes in the `dtrain`.